# Finding scaling factor of related datasets

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, data-fitting

I have two datasets from two sources vovering one signal and want to find the factor between the two.
They have different resolutions in x and y as well as one set being more noisy than the other.

the following gives a simple approximation, though the actual data does not follow an easy-to-fit polynomial.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

datax1 = np.linspace(0,100,1000)
datay1 = np.around(datax1,-1)**2

datax2 = np.linspace(0,100,80)+np.random.normal(0,0.2,80)
datay2 = (datax2**2)*np.random.normal(5,0.5)+np.random.normal(0,500,80)

plt.title('Data 1 VS Data 2')
plt.plot(datax1,datay1,'b',label='Data 1')
plt.plot(datax2,datay2,'r',label='Data 2')            
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('img.png', bbox_inches='tight', dpi=72)
```

[similar data, different noise and rez](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjSA0.png)

I need to automate finding this factor since I have more datasets to analyse, but SciPy's `curve_fit` does not play nice with `interpolate` as

```
import scipy.optimize as opt
import scipy.interpolate as interp

def func(x,k):
    fun=interp(datax1,datay1*k)
    return fun(x)
 
print opt.curve_fit(func,datax2,datay2)
```

only returns `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable` at the definition of `fun`

Is there any way to do this with numpy or scipy or do I have to build my own least-squares function to find the scaling of the data?

Comment: It's not that `curve_fit` is not playing nicely with `interpolate` but you are trying to call the module like a function. Regardless of `curve_fit`, do you know how to do interpolation?

Comment: honestly, all the documenation I've found uses interpolations like functions, for examples and plotting, so i figured it ought to work

Comment: or i've not used the proper subclass and thta's why nothing is working ... *facepalm*

Comment: `scipy.interpolate` is the module that contains all the interpolation stuff. You need to do something like `from scipy.interpolate import interp1d` and use that. (Assuming `interp1d` is the correct routine for you... there are others as well.)

Comment: yeah, that's the one.thank you

Comment: Do the two data sets have the same start end end points (apart from noise of course)?..noise in `y` only?